# Как переименовать атрибут в сериализторах pydantic?

Tags: python, pydantic

Есть подобная модель:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    attr1: str
    attr2: str
    attr3: str
```

Мне необходимо на выходе получить:

`{ attr_1: "someText", attr_2: "someText", attr_3: "someText" }`

Я знаю, что в `marshmallow` есть для этого параметр `attribute`, есть ли что-то подобное в `pydantic`?

Пробовал `alias`, но, кажется, это другое.

Answer (score 2):

Именно через `alias`. Пример:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    attr1: str = Field(alias="attr_1")
    attr2: str = Field(alias="attr_2")
    attr3: str = Field(alias="attr_3")
    
    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True


some_model = SomeModel(attr1="someText", attr2="someText", attr3="someText")
print(some_model)  # attr1='someText' attr2='someText' attr3='someText'
print(some_model.json(by_alias=True))  # {"attr_1": "someText", "attr_2": "someText", "attr_3": "someText"}
```

Вывод:

```
attr1='someText' attr2='someText' attr3='someText'
{"attr_1": "someText", "attr_2": "someText", "attr_3": "someText"}
```

Настройка `allow_population_by_field_name = True` тут используется, чтобы при создании объекта `SomeModel(attr1="someText", attr2="someText", attr3="someText")` можно было указывать внутренние имена атрибутов (по умолчанию при наличии псевдонима при создании объекта нужно указывать псевдонимы атрибутов).

Также, чтобы создавать псевдонимы автоматически, в `Config` можно указать функцию преобразования имен в псевдонимы, пример:

```
import re


def alias_generator(name: str):
    return '_'.join(re.search(r"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)", name).groups())


class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    attr1: str
    attr2: str
    attr3: str
    
    class Config:
        alias_generator = alias_generator
        allow_population_by_field_name = True


some_model = SomeModel(attr1="someText", attr2="someText", attr3="someText")
print(some_model)
print(some_model.json(by_alias=True))
```

Можно также использовать готовый пакет [`pyhumps`](https://pypi.org/project/pyhumps/), который умеет преобразовывать `snake_case` в `camelCase` или `PascalCase` и обратно (но правда не умеет преобразовывать `attr1` в `attr_1`, поэтому в предыдущем примере пришлось писать свою функцию). Пример:

```
import humps


class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    attr_one: str
    attr_two: str
    attr_three: str
    
    class Config:
        alias_generator = humps.camelize
        allow_population_by_field_name = True


some_model = SomeModel(attr_one="someText", attr_two="someText", attr_three="someText")
print(some_model)
print(some_model.json(by_alias=True))
```

Вывод:

```
attr_one='someText' attr_two='someText' attr_three='someText'
{"attrOne": "someText", "attrTwo": "someText", "attrThree": "someText"}`
```

Полезная статья: [CamelCase Models with FastAPI and Pydantic](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/camel-case-models-with-fast-api-and-pydantic-5a8acb6c0eee)